# SQL query for similar attribute in three tables with no overlap

Tags: postgresql

In our data, users' languages are stored in three fields: UI language in "core user" table, preferred language in "core profile" table and spoken language "language" table.

I am trying to write a SQL query that calculates all Spanish speakers (ES) from UI, Spanish speakers from preferred language (ES) and Spanish speakers (SPA) with no duplicates.

I think the best way is users that are ES from "core user" UI who are NOT in "core profile" ES preferred language and are also NOT in "language" SPA, with ES preferred language AND SPA (all). But I am not sure.

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Add table structure, sample data and desired result so the community is able to help.

Comment: Yet not well enough, you should check similar questions about database queries to see how to make a good question, still I will try to answer making some assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
with spanish_users as(
select user_id from core_user
where "UI_language" ='ES'
union
select user_id from core_profile
where preferred_language ='ES'
union
select user_id from "language" 
where spoken_language ='SPA')
select count(distinct user_id) from spanish_users;
```

working example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d196Ht6fxqd1Lw71cUyYUS/1